# How to get root password in Bitnami Wordpress from kubernetes shell?

Tags: wordpress, shell, kubernetes, kubectl, rancher

I have installed Worpress in Rancher, (*docker.io/bitnami/wordpress:5.3.2-debian-10-r43*) I have to make wp-config writable but I get stuck, when get shell inside this pod to log as root :

```
kubectl exec -t -i --namespace=annuaire-p-brqcw annuaire-p-brqcw-wordpress-7ff856cd9f-l9gf7 bash
```

I cannot login to root, no password match with Bitnami Wordpress installation.

```
wordpress@annuaire-p-brqcw-wordpress-7ff856cd9f-l9gf7:/$ su root
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
```

What is the default password, or how to change it ?

I really need your help!

Comment: Hi. Sorry but your problem sounds a bit off. How did you "install wordpress in Rancher"? I guess you somehow deployed the docker image you named to a Kubernetes Cluster? It would not make much sense to change any file "in" a container anyway as the change would be deleted when the pod gets recreated or the deployment gets update. Maybe have a look at the bitnami helm documentation to understand how the component work and interact https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/wordpress/

Comment: Yes I know that, but It's only for testing, I need to import a migration file, and I my wp-config configuration this file is too big.

Comment: Its in the documentation of the helm chart `The Bitnami WordPress image was migrated to a "non-root" user approach. `  `Consequences: - The HTTP/HTTPS ports exposed by the container are now 8080/8443 instead of 80/443.
 - No writing permissions will be granted on wp-config.php by default.`

Answer (score 0):

> The WordPress container has been migrated to a "non-root" user
> approach. Previously the container ran as the root user and the Apache
> daemon was started as the daemon user. From now on, both the container
> and the Apache daemon run as user 1001. You can revert this behavior
> by changing USER 1001 to USER root in the Dockerfile.
>
> No writing permissions will be granted on wp-config.php by default.

This means that the only way to run it as root user is to create own Dockerfile and changing user to `root`.

However it's  not recommended to run those containers are root for [security reasons](https://docs.bitnami.com/tutorials/work-with-non-root-containers/).

Comment: I understand, I will use Rancher only for testing, for these security reasons, no ssl configuration too.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and most native Kubernetes way to change the file content on the Pod's container file system is to create a [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/) object [from file](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#create-configmaps-from-directories) using the following command:

```
$ kubectl create configmap myconfigmap --from-file=foo.txt
$ cat foo.txt
foo test
```

(Check the [ConfigMaps documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/#mounted-configmaps-are-updated-automatically) for details how to update them.)

then mount the `ConfigMap` to your container to replace existing file as follows:
(example requires some adjustments to work with Wordpress image):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mypod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: mypod
    image: nginx
    volumeMounts:
    - name: volname1
      mountPath: "/etc/wpconfig.conf"
      readOnly: true
      subPath: foo.txt
  volumes:
  - name: volname1
    configMap:
      name: myconfigmap
```

In the above example, the file in the ConfigMap `data:` section replaces original `/etc/wpconfig.conf` file (or creates if the file doesn't exist) in the running container without necessity to build a new container.

```
$ kubectl exec -ti mypod -- bash
root@mypod:/# ls -lah /etc/wpconfig.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 9 Jun  4 16:31 /etc/wpconfig.conf
root@mypod:/# cat /etc/wpconfig.conf
foo test
```

Note, that the file permissions is 644 which is enough to be readable by non-root user.

BTW, Bitnami Helm chart also uses this approach, but it relies on the [existing configMap](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/c0942755d2f2f3a5df7dc8e36fd841a7419d55fa/bitnami/wordpress/templates/deployment.yaml#L219) in your cluster for adding custom `.htaccess` and [persistentVolumeClaim](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/c0942755d2f2f3a5df7dc8e36fd841a7419d55fa/bitnami/wordpress/templates/deployment.yaml#L228) for mounting Wordpress `data` folder.